# Drawing an arc with pstricks and latex2html5

Tags: circles, mathjax, arc

I get an issue about drawing an arc with MathJax and latex2html5 (from http://latex2html5.com/).

I would like to draw this schema with these 2 libraries above :

[image: Schema to repoduce]

Unfortunately, I can't get to reproduce this schema : you can check it on this [link][2]

My issue is that I can't draw the 2 arcs on the left which link `EV` and `DE` states.

On the link above, I did :

```
<script type="tex/latex">

\begin{center}
\begin{pspicture}(-4,-4)(4,4)

 \pscircle(-3.3,2.5){0.4}
 \pscircle(-3.3,-2.5){0.4}
 \pscircle(3.3,-2.5){0.4}
 \pscircle(3.3,2.5){0.4}

\psline{->}(-2.9,2.5)(2.9,2.5)
\rput(0,2.8){00}

\psline{->}(3.3,2.1)(3.3,-2.1)
\rput(3.6,0){00}

\psline{->}(2.9,-2.5)(-2.9,-2.5)
\rput(0,-2.8){01,11}

\psarc[fillcolor=white]{->}(-3.7,0){2}{-90}{90}

\end{pspicture}
\end{center}

  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  $('body').latex();
  </script>
```

The line :

```
\psarc[fillcolor=white]{->}(-3.7,0){2}{-90}{90}
```

concerns this part but the result is not good: first, fillcolor is blue and after, the interval of angle is not good too (I want the 2 arcs to be vertical).

If someone could help me, this would be fine.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know if I am on the suitable forum for this question, it may be redirected to MathJax issues on StackOverflow, anyone could do it if necessary ? thanks

Comment: As far as I can tell, the issue is with latex2html5's implementation of pstricks. I don't even see the `\psarc` command you've used in the [documentation](http://mathapedia.com/books/31/sections/176/subsections/187), although it does seem to be (partly) implemented in the [javascript](http://latex2html5.com/latex2html5.js). I guess you could request that feature from the maintainers (although it doesn't look actively maintained) or try to modify the js yourself to give the functionality you want.